# How can I apply a function element-wise to two arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy 1D arrays of strings and a function that takes two strings and generates an score based on some relations between the two input strings.

```
def get_score(string1, string2):
    # compute score ...
    return score
```

Is there an efficient way (perhaps using numpy) to apply that function to all combinations of the two arrays to generate an array with the scores from which I could select the max score?

Comment: No, there is no efficient solution in the sense that it would convert your operation to a fast vectorized one. You will essentially have to loop.

Comment: You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to easily iterate over all combinations of elements from two lists, but it'll be pretty slow for large inputs.

Comment: It may depend on the content of the function. Can you show your function?

Comment: If the function `get_score` can be vectorized, then you can apply it in a vectorized way without a Python loop. The time needed will be proportional to the product of the two list lengths.

Answer (score 1):

With a large set of operators and ufunc, numpy can easily do this kind of element-wise computation, using a fundamental concept of `broadcasting`:

```
In [155]: A = np.array(['one','two','three']); B = np.array(['four','two'])

In [156]: A[:,None] == B      # compare a (3,1) array with a (2,)
Out[156]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

But this works much better with numeric arrays.  There aren't many actions that work with string arrays.

A few of the `np.char` functions work with 2 arrays:

```
In [159]: np.char.join(B,A[:,None])
Out[159]: 
array([['ofournfoure', 'otwontwoe'],
       ['tfourwfouro', 'ttwowtwoo'],
       ['tfourhfourrfourefoure', 'ttwohtwortwoetwoe']], dtype='<U21')
```

Expanding the arrays into 2d arrays (functionally the same as `A[:,None]`):

```
In [160]: np.meshgrid(A,B,indexing='ij')
Out[160]: 
[array([['one', 'one'],
        ['two', 'two'],
        ['three', 'three']], dtype='<U5'),
 array([['four', 'two'],
        ['four', 'two'],
        ['four', 'two']], dtype='<U4')]
```

`np.vectorize` can be used to apply broadcasting to a function that takes scalar inputs (single strings).  For small arrays it tends to be slower than list comprehension, but for large arrays it scales somewhat better.

In short, there's a lot of power in `numpy` for doing numeric element-wise operations, less so for strings.